# Creating csv file with data having new lines and nullable column

Tags: mariadb

I am creating a CSV file using one table data as below, the table have newlines as part of data and some columns are nullable

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'outfile'  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' FROM T1;
```

Output:

```
"X\
YZ","ABC",1
"abc",\N,\N
```

When a newline is part of data then a newline is escaping with a backslash() in CSV but I don't want backslash.
When a column is null then data coming \N in CSV file and I don't want \N.

I want Output as below:

```
"X
YZ","ABC",1
"abc",,
```

Is there any way to achieve this in MariaDB?

Comment: what about "LINES TERMINATED BY"?

Comment: and you could replace all unwanted character in your Select